# how to check this function is not complex differentiable in 0

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

suppose we have the function $f(z) = e^{\frac{-1}{z^ 4}}$  if $z \neq 0$ and 0 elsewhere.
The question is why is this function not complex differentiable in 0?

So i thought lets look in 0. then f is complex diff if:

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$

note that $f(0) = 0$, then we get:

$lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z)}{z}$

isn' t this exactly the same which implies complex differentiability in $0$?

Any help would be much appreciated, what am i doing wrong?

Kees

Comment: The limit in question doesn't exist. If you approach $0$ through real or purely imaginary values, you have a limit, but ...

Comment: they are not the same i guess.... But i don't see why, because substituting $z$ in the form $x+iy$ and you let x or y go to $0$, will get you the exact same result right?

Comment: But not all complex numbers have $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: should it be differentiable from all sides? Can one not say it is complex differentiable if $x=0 \text{or} y=0$ or if $x=y$?

Comment: The limit must be the same regardless of the path of approach. So if you can find two paths to $0$ along which the limits are different, this shows the limit doesn't exist and so the function isn't differentiable at that point.

Comment: hmmm, i tried solving this problem but i still don´t get it... which path should i choose to see a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto e^{1/x}$ when $x\to0$ in some way serves as a counterexample in many situations. Here we have $f(z):=e^{-1/z^4}$; so this smells fishy to begin with. One suspects that even the limit doesn't exist. To make sure we have to produce a situation where this term actually goes to $\infty$ for suitable $z\to0$.

Put $z:=te^{i\pi/4}$ and let $t\to0+$. You shall see that $f$ is not even bounded near $0$. How could it be differentiable then?

Comment: nice example, it is something i wouldn´t think of myself though. Is there an easier way of seeing this?

Kees

Comment: Dear Prof. Blatter - I had upvoted this a short while ago. Maybe I could impose on you for an efficient way to show f(z) satisfies the C-R equations at $z=0$. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @Andrew: A function which is not even bounded near $z=0$ cannot be continuous at $0$, let alone be differentiable in any sense.